# How does MemoryCache know how much memory it uses?

Tags: .net, caching, memory-management

The `MemoryCache` class in `.net` is supposed to evict items whenever the amount of memory it uses exceeds some limit.

How does it actually determine how much memory its items are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MemoryCache` has an internal `CacheMemoryMonitor` that periodically asks its references how big they are. It utilizes an internal type in mscorlib called `SizedReference` which is a reference that also keeps track of how much memory (approximately) its target uses.

It also collects various statistics from the GC to help ascertain if memory pressure should cause it to start an eviction process.

Comment: So basically this means that `MemoryCache` will have a (good?) idea of the entire object graph stored into it, right? It's safe to assume that it's not as naive as simply adding up the object reference sizes associated to the keys of the internal Hashtable it uses, isn't it?

Comment: So… it is impossible to implement `MemoryCache` without knowing about .net and CLR internals?